# Iperf testing- Slow transfer speeds

Tags: bandwidth, fortigate, testing, iperf, iperf3

I'm doing Iperf testing at my company's branch office circuit and I'm getting results that are causing me concern.

I'm testing from a laptop through an access switch>distro switch> Fortigate> 10g circuit > Private test server in Azure with a public IP. The throuput in this testing is limited by 1g interface on the access switch. I can get pretty close to the 1G limit but the issues I have to set Iperf to do 50 streams to get that result. the individual streams are only getting 20-25 mbps (summary outputs below). I have done internal testing between Iperf3 servers on the LAN and I can get individual streams of nearly a gig.  Does anyone know why I may be getting this result? Could it be my MTU or MSS on the WAN interface?

Test Complete. Summary Results:
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  27.2 MBytes  22.9 Mbits/sec                  sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  27.2 MBytes  22.9 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[  6]   0.00-10.00  sec  27.0 MBytes  22.6 Mbits/sec                  sender
[  6]   0.00-10.00  sec  27.0 MBytes  22.6 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[  8]   0.00-10.00  sec  27.2 MBytes  22.9 Mbits/sec                  sender
[  8]   0.00-10.00  sec  27.2 MBytes  22.9 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 10]   0.00-10.00  sec  27.4 MBytes  23.0 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 10]   0.00-10.00  sec  27.4 MBytes  23.0 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 12]   0.00-10.00  sec  27.2 MBytes  22.9 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 12]   0.00-10.00  sec  27.2 MBytes  22.9 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 14]   0.00-10.00  sec  27.4 MBytes  23.0 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 14]   0.00-10.00  sec  27.4 MBytes  23.0 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 16]   0.00-10.00  sec  27.4 MBytes  23.0 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 16]   0.00-10.00  sec  27.4 MBytes  23.0 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 18]   0.00-10.00  sec  27.4 MBytes  23.0 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 18]   0.00-10.00  sec  27.4 MBytes  23.0 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 20]   0.00-10.00  sec  27.0 MBytes  22.6 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 20]   0.00-10.00  sec  27.0 MBytes  22.6 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 22]   0.00-10.00  sec  27.2 MBytes  22.9 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 22]   0.00-10.00  sec  27.2 MBytes  22.9 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 24]   0.00-10.00  sec  27.1 MBytes  22.7 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 24]   0.00-10.00  sec  27.1 MBytes  22.7 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 26]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.9 MBytes  22.5 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 26]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.9 MBytes  22.5 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 28]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.9 MBytes  22.5 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 28]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.9 MBytes  22.5 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 30]   0.00-10.00  sec  27.0 MBytes  22.6 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 30]   0.00-10.00  sec  27.0 MBytes  22.6 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 32]   0.00-10.00  sec  25.8 MBytes  21.6 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 32]   0.00-10.00  sec  25.8 MBytes  21.6 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 34]   0.00-10.00  sec  25.6 MBytes  21.5 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 34]   0.00-10.00  sec  25.6 MBytes  21.5 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 36]   0.00-10.00  sec  25.8 MBytes  21.6 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 36]   0.00-10.00  sec  25.8 MBytes  21.6 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 38]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.8 MBytes  22.4 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 38]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.8 MBytes  22.4 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 40]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.5 MBytes  22.2 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 40]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.5 MBytes  22.2 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 42]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.4 MBytes  22.1 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 42]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.4 MBytes  22.1 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 44]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.0 MBytes  21.8 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 44]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.0 MBytes  21.8 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 46]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.9 MBytes  22.5 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 46]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.9 MBytes  22.5 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 48]   0.00-10.00  sec  27.0 MBytes  22.6 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 48]   0.00-10.00  sec  27.0 MBytes  22.6 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 50]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.9 MBytes  22.5 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 50]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.9 MBytes  22.5 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 52]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.5 MBytes  22.2 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 52]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.5 MBytes  22.2 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 54]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.4 MBytes  22.1 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 54]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.4 MBytes  22.1 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 56]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.6 MBytes  22.3 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 56]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.6 MBytes  22.3 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 58]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.6 MBytes  22.3 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 58]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.6 MBytes  22.3 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 60]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.8 MBytes  22.4 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 60]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.8 MBytes  22.4 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 62]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.4 MBytes  22.1 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 62]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.4 MBytes  22.1 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 64]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.6 MBytes  22.3 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 64]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.6 MBytes  22.3 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 66]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.6 MBytes  22.3 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 66]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.6 MBytes  22.3 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 68]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.8 MBytes  22.4 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 68]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.8 MBytes  22.4 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 70]   0.00-10.00  sec  12.4 MBytes  10.4 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 70]   0.00-10.00  sec  12.4 MBytes  10.4 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 72]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.9 MBytes  22.5 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 72]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.9 MBytes  22.5 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 74]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.6 MBytes  22.3 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 74]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.6 MBytes  22.3 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 76]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.8 MBytes  22.4 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 76]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.8 MBytes  22.4 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 78]   0.00-10.00  sec  23.8 MBytes  19.9 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 78]   0.00-10.00  sec  23.7 MBytes  19.9 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 80]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.8 MBytes  22.4 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 80]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.8 MBytes  22.4 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[ 82]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.6 MBytes  22.3 Mbits/sec                  sender
[ 82]   0.00-10.00  sec  26.6 MBytes  22.3 Mbits/sec                  receiver
[SUM]   0.00-10.00  sec  1.03 GBytes   883 Mbits/sec                  sender
[SUM]   0.00-10.00  sec  1.03 GBytes   883 Mbits/sec                  receiver
CPU Utilization: local/sender 72.2% (22.6%u/49.7%s), remote/receiver 7.4% (0.8%u /6.6%s)

Comment: Hard to tell with the limited info you've provided.  Please edit your question to include all device models, relevant configurations, and a simple diagram.    We can't just guess.

Comment: *Private test server in Azure with a public IP* - you are basically testing your Internet access and Azure bandwidth. Make sure that your test endpoints support the TCP window scale option. Please add the iperf3 commands used to your question as well as the round-trip time between endpoints (at least ping).

Answer (score 1):

In my experience Azure throttle the traffic and you can only achieve limited performance on a single flow.

This is because aside the public access they sell the [express route](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/expressroute) circuit.

If you could achieve 1Gbs connection on public access they would not sell any express route.